# Access Parse Array Elements

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform

I have an array column in Parse that is called homeAddress. Inside it is the following value for a single row:

> ["111111","222222"]

I wish to access this in swift. I created a local array called homeAddress of String type. How can I store the first element in the Parse column (i.e. 111111) in the first element holder in local array i.e. homeAddress[0]? And then I need to store the 222222 in the homeAddress[1].

Comment: Are you trying to query this from parse to use in your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you want is load this data from parse. You can just call a Parse Query get the results and work with them:

```
let query = PFQuery(className:"ClassName")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
      (results, error) -> Void in
          if (error == nil) {
                for object in results!{
                    let homeAddress = object["homeAddress"] as! NSArray
                }
          }else {
                    print(error?.userInfo)
                }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to trim first and last character and just separate values by comma:

```
var test = "[\("111111"),\("222222")]"
var trimmedStringRange = Range<String.Index>(start: test.startIndex.successor(), end: test.endIndex.predecessor())
var homeAddress = test.substringWithRange(trimmedStringRange).componentsSeparatedByString(",")
```

Answer (score 0):

If your local array is empty, you can add your values from the parse array like this (after getting the array from Parse):

```
localHomeAddress.append(homeAddress)
```

This will put all values from `homeAddress` array in `localHomeAddress` array.

If you use a splice, you can ensure you are adding the values from index 0:

```
localHomeAddress.insertContentsOf(homeAddress, at:0)
```